# Path Tracing - Generate Camera Rays with a Left Handed coordinate system

Tags: rendering, raytracing

Been having some issues implementing a camera for my renderer. As the question states,I would like to know the necessary steps to generate such a camera.With field of view and aspect ratio included.Its important that the Coordinate system be left handed such that -z pushes the camera away from the screen(as I understand it).I have tried looking online but most of the implementations are incomplete or have failed me.Any help is appreciated.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this and took a long time to figure out. Here is the code for camera class.

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H_
#define CAMERA_H_

#include "common.h"

struct Camera {
    Vec3fa position, direction;
    float fovDist, aspectRatio;
    double imgWidth, imgHeight;
    Mat4 camMatrix;

    Camera(Vec3fa pos, Vec3fa cRot, Vec3fa cDir, float cfov, int width, int height) {
        position = pos;
        aspectRatio = width / (float)height;
        imgWidth = width;
        imgHeight = height;

        Vec3fa angle = Vec3fa(cRot.x, cRot.y, -cRot.z);
        camMatrix.setRotationRadians(angle * M_PI / 180.0f);

        direction = Vec3fa(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
        camMatrix.rotateVect(direction);

        fovDist = 2.0f * tan(M_PI * 0.5f * cfov / 180.0);
    }

    Vec3fa getRayDirection(float x, float y) {
        Vec3fa delta = Vec3fa((x-0.5f) * fovDist * aspectRatio, (y-0.5f) * fovDist, 0.0f);
        camMatrix.rotateVect(delta);
        return (direction + delta);
    }
};

#endif
```

Incase if you need the rotateVect() code in the Mat4 class

```
void Mat4::rotateVect(Vector3& vect) const
{
    Vector3 tmp = vect;
    vect.x = tmp.x * (*this)[0] + tmp.y * (*this)[4] + tmp.z * (*this)[8];
    vect.y = tmp.x * (*this)[1] + tmp.y * (*this)[5] + tmp.z * (*this)[9];
    vect.z = tmp.x * (*this)[2] + tmp.y * (*this)[6] + tmp.z * (*this)[10];
}
```

Here is our setRotationRadians code

```
void Mat4::setRotationRadians(Vector3 rotation)
{
    const float cr = cos(rotation.x);
    const float sr = sin(rotation.x);
    const float cp = cos(rotation.y);
    const float sp = sin(rotation.y);
    const float cy = cos(rotation.z);
    const float sy = sin(rotation.z);

    (*this)[0] = (cp * cy);
    (*this)[1] = (cp * sy);
    (*this)[2] = (-sp);

    const float srsp = sr * sp;
    const float crsp = cr * sp;

    (*this)[4] = (srsp * cy - cr * sy);
    (*this)[5] = (srsp * sy + cr * cy);
    (*this)[6] = (sr * cp);

    (*this)[8] = (crsp * cy + sr * sy);
    (*this)[9] = (crsp * sy - sr * cy);
    (*this)[10] = (cr * cp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Already implemented one but it's not the best and has certain issues.So, eager to try something else.Anyways few questions.What is the cam Matrix initialized to ? Is it the identity matrix or some other 4x4 Values.Secondly can I kindly see the set Rotation Radians code? I would like to compare something.And finally just a curiosity more than anything - Why use a matrix instead of the usual cross product methods? That's all.Again......Thanks a lot :)

Comment: CamMatrix is initialised to Identity Matrix. You can achieve the same thing without matrix, but I have recently become a fan of matrices, so I used it.

Comment: Oh ok.I guess we are all different.Cuz I really hate matrices.Lol.Wont use them until absolutely necessary.Anyways thanks for everything.Will let you know as soon as I try it !! The code makes perfect sense.

Comment: Plz update here if the answer was useful. Also, I once hated Matrices like you do, then after understanding them enough, now started loving them

Comment: Yes I found it very useful !! Thanks.Still using the old right handed one.But I was able to help a friend who is also implementing one with the information provided here.So... thanks again. :)